# Validate HTML code programmatically

Tags: java, html, testing, tidy, jtidy

I am trying to validate a `String` of HTML code. That is, when HTML code syntax is wrong I want to know, perhaps in the form of a `return false`.

I am currently using [JTidy](http://jtidy.sourceforge.net/) but it doesn't tell me there was bad syntax it just corrects it. **I don't need to correct it just say if the synthax is bad or good.**

JTidy code:

```
String s = "<td>cookie<td>";  // bad syntax.
Tidy tidy = new Tidy();

InputStream stream = new ByteArrayInputStream(s.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
tidy.parse(stream, System.out);
```

Any help is appriciated.

Comment: Why is `<td>cookie<td>` bad syntax?

Comment: As far as I know `<td>cookie</td>` is the correct way because of the terminating `/`

Comment: The closing `</td>` tag is optional in HTML, so `<td>cookie<td>`, in the right context, means two table cells, and is not invalid.

Comment: JTidy marks things like that as warnings. Should I just dismiss them? For example I keep getting `<Form1>` should be `</Form1>`. If you could show me what an error would look like I woul deeply appriciate it!

Answer (score 0):

java has inbuilt **DOM Parser** in it.
Use DOM Parser to check. It will also show errors.